# Is it really true that valence band is completely filled at zero temperature?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, low-temperature-physics

Is it really true that valence band is completely filled at null temperature?

Indeed, I would think that if we apply an electric field, this would give some energy to the electrons from the valence band, so would they be prevented to leave the valence band to go to the conduction band, thanks to the energy from the electric field?

I don't see why would the electrons know if the energy that they receive is due to temperature or from electric field source?

Comment: Just because you have a field, how will you excite a valence electron to the conduction band?

Comment: Jon, here is my interpretation. Tell me where is my mistake. Thank you. Whenever there is an electric fiel, there is a correspondind electric potential, which is an energy. So with this energy the electron moves to the conduction band. ?

Comment: So, at non-zero temperature, you would expect carrier concentrations to increase during conduction? Under any applied field?

Comment: Jon: maybe you were meaning at "zero temperature" : I would expect that in presence of electric field, there is electric current, and from The Photon, I would deduce that the temperature increase, thus the electrons receive more energy and go in the conduction further, with a stable behaviour because the temperature is not diverging of course. So yes, at non zero temperature, the carrier concentration would increase during a *transient* time before stability.

Comment: Two things to consider, then. First, carrier concentrations in semiconductors are not observed to increase during current flow - such a mechanism is not needed to explain or understand device performance. Second, a full band does not conduct current.

Comment: yes, but I believe that the trick is just that the theory about full band and null temperature is just "playing with words" : when the electric field appear, the temperature increases, thus the full band is no more full, and the electron move to conduction band, and the electric current appears. If I understand, in *your* interpretation, if we would be able to have experimentally speaking a null temperature, you would say that if I apply an electric field, there is no electric current, while in my interpretation, the electric current would appear.

Comment: If current does not flow, how does putting a static field across a material increase the electron (or material) temperature? By that logic, you should be able to generate carriers in, say, sapphire.

Comment: From the static field E, we have E=-grad V (where is the electric potential), and we have potential energy=e*V, so there is an energy on the electron of the valence band. If the energy applied by the electric field is above the gap value, by definition, the electron should go to the conduction band. If the electron moves, the temperature increases, since temperature represents agitation of particles. I don't know properties of sapphire. Anyway, it would be good to have the answer from a theoretician researcher in semiconductors, in order to have a definitive answer on my question.

Comment: First point: exciting carriers from the valence to conduction bands with a static electric field in a bulk semiconductor is possible, but it's **really** hard. J. M. Ziman talks about this (Zener tunneling) in "Principles of the theory of solids". You'd need a super high field. Second point: strictly speaking, temperature is an equilibrium property. Now, usually that doesn't stop us from talking about temperature when things are fairly static. However, if you're using a humongous field to excite the electrons, you are nowhere close to equilibrium; the temperature is undefined. It's not zero.

Comment: Hello Inmaurer. I don't understand why we would need tunneling, and why the field should be high. The field should just be the difference of energy between the valence band and the conduction band, nothing more, so why "high" ?

Comment: Could you explain how an electric field can equate to a difference in energy? The units aren't the same. An electric field accelerates an electron, giving it a little more kinetic energy. However, if you are at the top of the valence band, you can't add a little more kinetic energy because of the band gap. A little more kinetic energy doesn't get you anywhere. There are literally no states an electron can go into. This is, effectively, an energy barrier, and the way to get through it it tunneling. See the reference I gave above.

Comment: Inmaurer. Thank you for your important question : "Could you explain how an electric field can equate to a difference in energy?". Here is my answer : tell me if I interpret wrongly : I would improve myself. My interpretation is that whenever you have an electric field E, this electric field E derives from an electric potential V (units is Volts). Then, whenever you have an electric potential V, and a charged particle, it exists an electric potential energy : eV, where e is the charge of the electron. So when we apply an electric field to an electron, we give it energy. Do you disagree ?

Comment: so my point is that if the electric field is high enough as to have eV above or equal to the band gap, the electron from the valence band will just to the conduction band. I don't see why we would need a "huge" energy for that : just the necessary energy corresponding to the gap. No need to have thermal form for the energy. I don't see why people need non null temperature for that.

Comment: For silicium, the gap is 1.12 eV. one eV=1.6e-10 J, so I guess that we should apply a strong electric field since we need around 1.6e-10 Joules. Would just applying a electric voltage of around 1 V enough to make the electron to move from the valence to the conduction band ?

Comment: That will not work. Don't take my word for it, try the following experiment: buy an intrinsic Si wafer (they're cheap), attach leads, dunk it in liquid nitrogen, and apply some voltage. If you put 1.12 V across it, the current will effectively be zilch. 100 V? Ditto. Insulators don't become conductors by putting a small voltage across them. No electronics would work if your model were correct. Electrons in crystals are weird. See the following related example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_oscillation

Comment: Sure but where is the error in my theoretical reasoning ? If I didn t do a mistake it would mean that the theory would be wrong

Comment: I explained the problem with your reasoning previously. An electric field accelerates an electron, but it **cannot** be accelerated into an energy where a state does not exist --- i.e. an energy that falls in the band gap. A band gap is like saying that you can drive a car at any speed except that it is **impossible** to drive between 10 and 20 mph. If you're driving at 9.99999 mph and you depress the accelerator a little more, nothing will happen; it is impossible to go a little faster. Your only option is to go instantaneously from 10 to 20 mph, and that would take an extremely large force.

Comment: Sure but as I told you there is *only* 1 eV between valence band and conduction band so it is tiny. I m not sure that your argument work isn it ?

Comment: Only?!? 1 eV is huge! It's equivalent to to over 11 **thousand** Kelvin! If it's the kinetic energy of a particle with the mass of an electron, that particle would be moving **593,096 m/s**! For an electron, there is nothing small about an electron volt.

Comment: But I thought that 1 eV is the energy that an electron accumulates when submitted to an electric tension of 1 Volt. 1 Volt is tiny. Sorry please help me for this last question.

Comment: I checked your computation : I agree that the particle will go to a high speed with an energy of 1 eV, but it is just normal : the mass of electron is tiny. You play with words. 1 eV is a tiny energy, "easy" to produce. Just with a battery of 1 V, we accelerate an electron to 1 eV. And by the way, in accelerators, as LHC, they accelerate particles at 7000 x1e9 eV. So 1 eV is just extremely easy. Would you have a *valid theoretical argument* to explain why a 1.2 V would not allow the electron to go to the conduction band ? Thank you

Comment: I have given a valid argument twice! I referenced a book that you can read for more details! I linked to a related phenomenon showing the difficulties with accelerating electrons! Instead of acknowledging any of this, you accuse me of playing with words?!? Clearly I’m wasting my time, but I’ll try once more: at 0 K, going from the valence to conduction band requires tunneling. (See above.) A 1 eV band gap is like a 1 eV rectangular barrier. For intuition, find the probability that a 0.1 eV electron tunnels through a 1 eV barrier that’s 1 nm thick. Square that with the “smallness” of an eV.

Comment: For your convenience, a calculator already exists: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Comment: Now, what happens if you make that barrier even a little larger? 2 nm? 10 nm? Those numbers are still tiny. What happens when you take your all-powerful AAA battery and put it across a 1 mm sample of Si? (For the record, a trapezoidal barrier is more appropriate in this situation than a rectangular one [a constant field causes a linear potential], but those are harder to work with and produce qualitatively similar results.)

Comment: Thank you Inamurer. Now I understand your explanations. But still, would you know why wikipedia says the opposite to you : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-conducteur#Principe_de_la_structure_en_bandes    It says : "Dans les semi-conducteurs, ...cette valeur [Gap] est plus petite (1,12 eV pour le silicium, .... Si l'on apporte cette énergie (ou plus) aux électrons, par exemple en chauffant le matériau, *ou en lui appliquant un champ électromagnétique*, ..., les électrons sont alors capables de passer de la bande de valence à la bande de conduction, et de circuler dans le matériau. "

Comment: the translation is that wikipedia says that there are *various ways* to move the electron from the valence to the conduction band : by temperature, *by electromagnetic field*, by light. This looks in contradiction with your explanation, isn't it ?

Comment: It is hard (not impossible) to do with a *static* electric field in a *bulk* semiconductor. If the field is not static or the material is not bulk, then it can be significantly easier to do. Light is not a static electric field, and a photon-electron interaction is very different from the case we discussed; a photon-electron interaction can give an electron the instantaneous kick it needs to cross the gap. No tunneling needed. Also, by heterogeneously doping the semiconductor, you can build in a very strong electric field that makes tunneling possible -- forming a Zener diode.

Comment: (Or the very similar Esaki diode.)

Comment: You forgot to add semiconductor in your description, other types of conductors/insulators have also valence and conduction bands.

Answer (score 1):

If a perfect semiconductor/insulator is at zero temperature, than indeed all its electrons are in the valence band, and exciting them to the conduction band requires, as a minimum, the gap energy, $E_g$.

If a uniform electric field is applied, then, obviously, there will be degeneracy between the valence band and the conduction band states, separated by distance of order
$$eEd=E_g$$
(More precisely, we have to recalculate the states of the crystal, taking into account the electric field, since the translation symmetry is broken now in one direction.) This degeneracy results in electrons tunneling from the valence band to the conduction band, which is a kind of dielectric breakdown, known as [Zener effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_effect).

However, in practice this effect is observed only at very large electric fields or in artificially created materials with small band gap (superlattices). The reason for that is that the tunneling is possible only when the tunneling length is comparable to the coherence lengths, which is usually rather short in  real materials.

Note also, that in a real material the imperfections (dislocations, impurities, etc.) will typically result in both valence and conduction band having tails extending well into the gap, so there might be always a residual concentration of electrons and holes, even at zero temperature - but too low to result in detectable electric conductance.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature we're talking about here isn't the temperature of the room where you do the experiment, or even the temperature of the atoms in the material. It's the temperature of the ensemble of electrons in the material.

If you had a sample of semiconductor with its electrons at 0 K, and you did something to it (apply an electric field or anything else) that promotes some electrons to the conduction band, then we'd say the electrons are no longer at 0 K.

It's possible they're not in a (quasi) thermal equilibrium state and we can't even describe them with a temperature. Or that their energy distribution is close enough to what we expect in some equilibrium state and we say they have a temperature $T$ with $T>0$.

The important thing is that temperature is a simplified description of the distribution of energy in some material or ensemble of particles. So if you change the energy distribution (by promoting some particles to a different energy level), you've changed their temperature (or possibly made it impossible to define their temperature).

Comment: Thank you The Photon. I'm 100 % convinced that people mean really the *temperature of the solid*. I believe that the genuine explanation is that if we apply an electric field, the electrons will move to the conduction band (thus Jon Custer is wrong). But due to the energy corresponding to the electric field, the temperature will increase, thus we are no more at null temperature. Do people agree with this explanation ? Then it means that saying that at null temperature there are only electrons in the valence band is just a "tautology" that bring information. Do you agree with my reformulation ?

Comment: see wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands :  "the valence band is the highest range of electron energies in which electrons are normally present at absolute zero temperature". And there are many web sites : the temperature is the temperature of the solid : it is not a "pseudo/modelizatoin temperature". It is a real temperature.

Comment: I believe that a "good description" of the valence band would be "the highest band that is completely filled at null temperature *and in absence of any other excitation*". Let's see comments.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, if you already know the answer, and won't accept that anyone answering you might have different insights, why did you bother to ask the question?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, It's not a tautology. Knowing the temperature of the electron gas and the temperature of the lattice, you know whether energy flows from one to the other or vice versa when they interact (which they do).

Comment: The Photon : I didn't have the answer (I am not losing my time to ask questions for which I would have the answers). This is thanks to  your explanation that *now*, I understand that the genuine answer is a small variante to your answer. Do you agree with my answer ?