# At null temperature, why an electric field would not allow an electron from the valence band to go in the conduction band?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

With *thermic energy* (increasing the temperature), the electron can move from the valence band to the conduction band. With another source of energy, as the energy from a static electric field, why would this source of energy not allow the electron to do the same, even at a null temperature ?

I asked a similar question in the past :
[Is it really true that valence band is completely filled at null temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503638/is-it-really-true-that-valence-band-is-completely-filled-at-null-temperature)

but people escaped a bit the question. Only the points suggested by Inmaurer was interesting, but he didn't go deep enough nor demontrated theoretically his point of view.

Would somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a strong enough electric field, an electron *can* go from the  valence to conduction band. This is called the Zener effect. More accurately it is *Zener tunneling*, as the "Zener effect" is also used for other effects in pn junctions.

Comment: Thank you mike stone. You are the first one that really answered to my question. All others were escaping the question. A last question : then, does it mean that those sentences that state that valence band is "full at null temperature" are wrong sentences, since for example, with strong electric field, even at T=0, it would not be the case, according to the Zener effect, since some electrons would escape to the conduction band, thus the valence band would not be full, even at T=0 ?

Comment: The statement about 0 temperature is not wrong. Once the zener effect has promoted an electron to the conduction band, the electron gas is no longer at zero temperature.

Comment: For the record, the first thing I wrote in the other thread referenced Zener tunneling. I'm glad this explanation was accepted after it was repeated again by another person.

Comment: Inmaurer. You are right. At this time it was not clear. Thank you.

Comment: Inmaurer. For the other article i believe your answer should replace the one of the photon. The photon told wrong things that temperature is not the one of the room. It is since there is equilibrum